# How to get dimension from import SVG component - nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

I import an SVG file as a component and try to get its dimension but it returns null. Can anyone give me the advice to achieve this.

PS. getBBox() does not work it give me an error.

Code example:

```
import IconSVG from 'public/images/my-svg.svg';
  
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <IconSVG ref={myRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Depending on the format of your svg you can get the `viewBox` attribute, some times svg have `width` and `height` attributes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you have to use [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myRef = React.useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      console.log(node.current.getBoundingClientRect()); // get dimensions
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <IconSVG ref={myRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about ref callbacks until now

Comment: Glad this helped.